# SBT Xsbt-web plugin not finding annotations

Tags: scala, jetty, classpath, atmosphere, xsbt-web-plugin

I have created an atmosphere framework application. When I use Xsbt container:start it does not scan the assembly and find the annotations on my classes.

However, when I package the project as a war and deploy to tomcat, it works perfectly.

It looks like there is a classpath issue but I am not sure how to start diagnosing this. I'm not finding much by googling or tinkering

If I manually copy the classes into webapp/WEB-INF/classes and the libs into webapp/lib/ then the application works, but the debugging for atmosphere does not.

I know that sbt is adding my dependencies in /home/me/.ivy2

Comment: What kind of annotations are you using?  Support for Jetty Annotations wasn't [added until version 0.7.0](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/blob/master/notes/0.7.0.markdown#changelog), so upgrading might help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by telling sbt to output my class files to the web-inf directory where atmosphere requires them to be put:

```
classDirectory in Compile := file("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes")
```

Comment: weird, this did not work for me (for the same problem)—which version of Jetty are you on?